# how to play youtube video with sound in wxpython window?

Tags: python, youtube, accessibility, wxpython

I am making a simple youtube player and downloader app accessible for blind people with screenreaders, but also usable by sighted people.
I chose wxpython because it has best accessibility ever.
How to play a youtube video in the wx window? Do I need to use `wx.media.MediaCtrl` and how to correctly use it?
can I play youtube video without downloading it right in the wxpython window?

I tried using `wx.media.MediaCtrl`, but I downloaded the video from youtube and then made it to show the video.
upd:
media control doesn't play anything. I used my own modified version of pafy that uses yt_dlp library and it perfectly gave me a working video stream url, however when I insert it into wx media, it doesn't play.

```
import wx
import wx.media
import pafy
from webbrowser import open as wopen
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch
from accessible_output2.outputs import auto


class YoutubePlayer(wx.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Youtube Player", size=(640, 480))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.edit_box = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, pos=(10, 10), size=(200, 20))
        self.list_box = wx.ListBox(self.panel, pos=(10, 40), size=(200, 400))
        self.media_player = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self.panel)
        self.media_player.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.on_media_loaded)
        self.edit_box.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_search)
        self.output = auto.Auto()
        self.results={}

    def on_search(self, event):
        query = self.edit_box.GetValue()
        self.output.output("Searching for " + query)
        search = VideosSearch(query, limit=10)
        items = search.result()["result"]
        video_ids = [item["id"] for item in items]
        video_titles = [item["title"] for item in items]
        self.list_box.SetItems(video_titles)
        self.media_player.Stop()
        self.results={k: v for k, v in zip(video_titles, video_ids)}

    def on_media_loaded(self, event):
        print("loaded")
        self.output.output("Playing")
        self.media_player.Play()

    def play_video(self, video_id):
        url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"
        video = pafy.new(url)
        best = video.getbest()
        play_url = best.url
        # wopen(play_url)
        self.media_player.LoadURI(play_url)

    def on_list_select(self, event):
        self.output.output("loading")
        video_id = self.results[event.GetString()]
        self.play_video(video_id)

    def on_list_double_click(self, event):
        self.on_list_select(event)

    def bind_list_events(self):
        #self.list_box.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.on_list_select)
        self.list_box.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK, self.on_list_double_click)

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    player = YoutubePlayer()
    player.bind_list_events()
    player.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`wx.media` will play direct from a URL, although I have no idea if it can access a YouTube url directly (I'm not a fan).

Here's a very bare bones player accessing a url rather than a file.

I would suggest that you test the media link to see if it is a url or a file, then use `LoadURI` or `Load` depending on the outcome.

```
import wx
import wx.media

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Media Player')
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(500, 700))
        self.player = wx.media.MediaCtrl(panel, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.stop = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Stop")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.player, 1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        sizer.Add(self.stop, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.media = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4'
        self.player.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play)
        self.player.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.quit)
        self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_STOP, self.quit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.quit, self.stop)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.quit)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(250)
        if self.player.LoadURI(self.media):
            pass
        else:
            print("Media not found")
            self.quit(None)
        self.Show()

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        if self.player.GetState() == wx.media.MEDIASTATE_PLAYING:
            print("Progress:",self.player.Tell())

    def play(self, event):
        self.player.Play()

    def quit(self, event):
        self.timer.Stop()
        if self.player.GetState() == wx.media.MEDIASTATE_PLAYING:
            self.player.Stop()
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Frame = TestPanel()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Worthy of note, you may have to choose your backend player via the `szBackend` parameter.

Available options are:

- MEDIABACKEND_DIRECTSHOW
- MEDIABACKEND_QUICKTIME
- MEDIABACKEND_GSTREAMER
- MEDIABACKEND_WMP10

If you want something more complicated than `wx.media` offers, you will have to roll your own.

`Gstreamer` and `Vlc` both work well on Linux, on other operating systems, I have no idea.

Edit:

If you must stream direct from youtube, use something like `pafy` to isolate the url.

For the above code:

add `import pafy`

instead of specifying the url to `self.media` replace

`self.media = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4'`

with the following:

```
#       youtube url via pafy
        url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iL-jC7XyLeo"
        video = pafy.new(url)
        best = video.getbest()
        playurl = best.url
        self.media = playurl
```

Then continue as above

Comment: thank you. youtube is not a direct streaming thing, so i must manually get the streaming link for a youtube video or parse youtube api...

Comment: @denizsincar29 Let `pafy` or something similar do the hard work for you

Comment: video is not playing. with no reason. can you help me?